# Is it possible to hook API calls on Mac OS?

Tags: macos

On Windows there a few libraries that allow you to intercept calls to DLLs:

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/hooksys.aspx

Is it possible to do this on Mac OS? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want to do this in your own application or systemwide.  In your own application, it's pretty easy; the dynamic linker provides features such as [`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).  If you're doing this for debugging/instrumentation purposes, also check out DTrace.

You can replace Objective-C method implementations with method swizzling, e.g. [JRSwizzle](http://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) or Apple's [`method_exchangeImplementations`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW54) (10.5+).

If you want to modify library behavior systemwide, you're going to need to load into other processes' address spaces.

- Two loading mechanisms originally designed for other purposes ([input managers](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?InputManager) and [scripting additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn1164)) are commonly abused for this purpose, but I wouldn't really recommend them.
- [`mach_inject/mach_override`](http://github.com/boredzo/mach_star/) are an open-source set of libraries for loading code and replacing function implementations, respectively; however, you're responsible for writing your own application which uses the libraries.  (Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258600/elevating-rights-to-use-mach-inject); you need special permissions to inject code into other processes.)

Please keep in mind that application patching/code injection for non-debugging purposes is strongly discouraged by Apple and some Mac users (and developers) are extremely critical of the practice.  Much of this criticism is poorly informed, but there have been a number of legitimately poorly written "plug-ins" (particularly those which patch Safari) that have been implicated in application crashes and problems.  Code defensively.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of a (free) APE module and an application which uses `mach_inject`.)

Comment: the link is dead there is any update ? I'm talking about the SDK

Comment: APE is basically unsupported now and there hasn't been an official release for several OS revisions — your best bet is mach_inject.

Comment: `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` is now ignored on El Capitan and above thanks to SIP.