# Is there a way to inject an OS X system framework system-wide?

Tags: objective-c, macos, hook, code-injection, objective-c-runtime

I need to get notified when a app (including system app/server) calls System Framework (`CoreServices.framework`). I am not sure whether Code Injection works on system-wide frameworks.

Is it possible to replace a system framework with my own copy, and then forward messages to the real one?

Comment: There's a lot of existing work for tracing system level calls built in to DTrace. You may be able to do what you want system wide without injecting anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) environment variable, but that only works with applications that you start, not system wide. More info [here](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2007/12/21/overriding-library-functions-in-mac-os-x-the-easy-way-dyld_insert_libraries/).

You can override system functions with [mach_override](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_override), but it requires root privivaleges or the procmod group. mach_override was released at MacHack 2003. From a quick glance, it looks as easy as one function call.

```
mach_override_ptr(&orginalFunction, &overrideFunction, NULL);
```

Please note that system-wide overriding is strongly discouraged for non-debugging applications.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689348/is-it-possible-to-hook-api-calls-on-mac-os).