# How do I intercept an OS X API call in an app

Tags: macos

I am using a 3rd party library that invokes a Core Foundation function.

Since that lib has a bug, passing incorrect values to a CF function, I need to intercept that call to fix the passed values.

How do I hook into the CF function call so that I can look at the passed parameters, change them and then call the actual (original) function?

I have the impression I can get to the actual function with the `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName`, passing `CFBundleGetMainBundle()`as the first parameter and the name of the CF function as the second parameter.

In my particular case, that would be:

```
void *p = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName (CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "CFRunLoopTimerCreate");
```

But that returns NULL.

I also tried this:

```
void *p = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName (CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier("com.apple.Cocoa"), "CFRunLoopTimerCreate");
```

That returns a non-null value but it still does not appear to be a pointer I could change but rather the actual starting address of the function's code.

So, how do I get an  address of a *function pointer* to an imported API function that I can save and then change to point to my intercepting function? Or how else could I hook into an imported function?

Answer (score 1):

`CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName` will just return the address of a function in a given bundle; this will never let you change the destination of calls to the function. If you really want to do something like that, please refer to [Is it possible to hook API calls on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689348/is-it-possible-to-hook-api-calls-on-mac-os) Note that this is highly not recommended.

Comment: It appears that the "highly not recommended" part only applies to system-wide interceptions. I only want to intercept the call in my own app. But I also don't have any understanding how to use the quoted `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` for that as I'm using a development system that doesn't let me write my own linked commands.

Comment: BTW, as I recall how external (imported) function calls work, it's always using an interim jmp call or something similar, meaning that all calls for a function generated by a compiler will jump to a single address, which will then perform the actual jump into the other dylib. So all I want to understand is how to reliably find that central point and patch it so that it calls my hook instead.